Import of fbx models
Could anyone shed some light as to why when I import a model done in  Mcad software and then converted to fbx it comes into blender more or less exploded into various parts, same happens if I try DAE  see  attached screenshot. The hydrauic cylinder should come in as fully assembled.

This has to do with your export settings in that software. Blender doesn't do much to an FBX file on import, unless that file had animations built-in.
